# Visual Studio 2013 with TFS online using Git: Saving files checks-in automatically

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2013, checkin

I'm currently using Visual Studio Premium 2013 Update 3 with Team Foundation Server Online and using a Git Repo.  I've been using the Git Repo successfully for months up until recently.  Now whenever I save a file, Visual Studio acts like the file was checked-in.  Files no longer show in Included Changes, Excluded Changes, or Untracked Files once they've been saved.  I added around 6 new projects to the solution today and every one of them started-out with the proper (add) icon, but upon working in Studio and saving files throughout the day, they all now have a lock icon and show as "Checked In".

I can remove a project or file and add it back, which causes the check-out symbol, but as soon as I save all changes, they're back to checked-in.

Sync with the online repo doesn't propagate the changes so they're not really being recognized as checked-in changes.

Has anyone else experienced this issue and found a solution?

UPDATE: This is likely specific to renaming the solution file.  I had renamed the solution file and after doing this the problem occurred.  After following the steps listed in the answer below and committing/syncing with the online repository, opening the solution back up now works normally again.

Comment: Have you used 'git status' from the command line to see if files are actually being added to your local git repo? And do you have any git hooks configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tip about 'git status' lead me to a solution.  I'm not sure exactly how this worked or what the root cause of the issue was, but these steps put me back on track:

1. Navigate to Team -> Connect to Team Foundation Server
2. Right-click the project listed on xxx.visualstudio.com and choose 'Connect'
3. Click the project name at the top, and choose 'Changes'
4. Choose 'Actions' next to the commit button and pick 'Open Command Prompt'
5. Type 'git status'
6. Assuming you actually have changes listed in the command window - Navigating back to 'Changes' in Visual Studio should now show all the Included & Excluded changes in Visual Studio

I'll follow-up if this actually solves the automatic check-in issue I was having with the solution as-well.

Comment: This did make the changes show up, but after the commit any new changes are automatically showing checked in, even if I haven't recommited.