# Visual Studio with GitHub checking in changes on save

Tags: visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2013, version-control

I've been working with several projects I have hosted on GitHub, but recently I haven't been able to check in any changes. Every time I save a file, VS treats the file as if it's checked in, lock icon and all. I can't make any commits because of this. I've had this occur in VS2013 Community, VS2013 Pro, and VS2015 Ultimate CTP. While restarting VS works in the 2013 versions, it does not work in 2015.

While searching for an answer, I came across [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25840607/visual-studio-2013-with-tfs-online-using-git-saving-files-checks-in-automatical). The answer ***did not*** work for me, as I am using GitHub, not TFS with a Git project ("Connect To" wouldn't show my project). In addition, I have not renamed any of the projects that have had this glitch. Is there anything I can do besides report the bug to MS?

Comment: Either nobody knows the answer, nobody knows what I'm talking about, or nobody seems to ever have this bug.

Answer (score 0):

To all the people which have this kind of problem using Visual Studios Git Source control.

One solution which worked for me since all other i found failed was to create a .gitignore file via Visual Studio. This somehow stopped the automatic check in which happened during a filesave.

Team Explorer -> Settings -> Repository Settings -> Ignore & Attributes section -> Ignore File -> Add

I am currently using Visual Studio 2015 update 1.